# Algebraic Geometry for Statistics

Tags: references, algebraic-statistics

I have heard about uses of Algebraic Geometry in Statistics and Machine Learning. I wanted to try to learn a bit about this topics. I don't know nearly anything about Algebraic Geometry, but I have background in math, and I know about basic group theory, rings fields and some commutative algebra. My questions are:

1. What are the Algebriac Geometric concepts I should learn that are connected to applications in Stats/ML (I suppose only a portion of what is usually taught in Algebraic Geometric courses and books is useful).
2. Can you recommend some books / introductory papers for someone with my background? I don't mean standard textbooks for AG but something that focuses on concepts used in applications.

Comment: You might start with M. Drton, B. Sturmfels, and S. Sullivant, *[Lectures on Algebraic Statistics](http://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/owl.pdf)*, Springer, 2009.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a list of the standard references:

- Drton, Sturmfels, and Sullivant, *[Lectures on Algebraic Statistics](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebernd/owl.pdf)*
- Pachter, Sturmfels, *[Algebraic Statistics for Computational Biology](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/pachter-algebraic.pdf)*
- Pistone, Riccomagno, Wynn, *[Algebraic Statistics: Computational Commutative Algebra in Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584882042)*
- Sullivant, [*Algebraic Statistics*](http://www4.ncsu.edu/%7Esmsulli2/Pubs/asbook.html)
- Zwiernik, [*Semialgebraic Statistics and Latent Tree Models*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466576219)
- Riccomagno, *[A Short History of Algebraic Statistics*](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/35494/1/WRAP_Riccomagno_08-21w.pdf)

Here is a list of related references, not directly addressing algebraic statistics, although providing background in the methodology used for the subject:

- Lauritzen, [*Graphical Models*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198522193)
- Lauritzen, [*Concrete Abstract Algebra*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521534100)
- Pearl, [*Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference*](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/)
- Cox, Little, O'Shea, [*Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319167200)
- Garrity, Belshoff, Boos, et al, [*Algebraic Geometry: A Problem-Solving Approach*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821893963)
- Sturmfels, [*Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations*](https://web.math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebernd/cbms.pdf)
- Uhler, [*Geometry of Maximum Likelihood Estimation in Graphical Models*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2643)

Web pages of courses about the topic, past and present:

- [Professor Sturmfels's course at Berkeley](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebernd/stat260.html)
- [Course at the TU Berlin](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Emohammad/AlgStat.html)$^\dagger$
- [Seminar at the Freie Universität, Berlin](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/shanekelly/algstat2016-2017winter.html)$^\dagger$
- [Conference at the University of Genoa](http://www.dima.unige.it/%7Erogantin/AS2015/)
- [Berkeley Algebraic Statistics Seminar](http://acritch.com/bass/)

These lists are almost certainly by no means comprehensive.

--

$\dagger$ links dead and not archived

Answer (score 7):

- Sumio Watanabe, [Algebraic Geometry and Statistical Learning Theory](http://watanabe-www.math.dis.titech.ac.jp/users/swatanab/ag-slt.html), Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK, 2009.

[image]

> Sure to be influential, this book lays the foundations for the use of
>   algebraic geometry in statistical learning theory. Many widely used
>   statistical models and learning machines applied to information
>   science have a parameter space that is singular: mixture models,
>   neural networks, HMMs, Bayesian networks, and stochastic context-free
>   grammars are major examples. Algebraic geometry and singularity theory
>   provide the necessary tools for studying such non-smooth models. Four
>   main formulas are established:
>
> 1. the log likelihood function can be given a common standard form using resolution of singularities, even applied to more complex
>      models;
> 2. the asymptotic behaviour of the marginal likelihood or 'the evidence' is derived based on zeta function theory;
> 3. new methods are derived to estimate the generalization errors in Bayes and Gibbs estimations from training errors;
> 4. the generalization errors of maximum likelihood and a posteriori methods are clarified by empirical process theory on algebraic
>      varieties.

Comment: Thank you for the reference -- this book looks like the best recommendation so far! I will have to get it soon. Also for anyone interested here is a question on this website about this book: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22391/estimation-and-functional-space